# Case statement with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can you help me write a `SELECT` statement that returns a single row having columns for each TypeId involved for the transaction number 55?

```
CREATE TABLE Types
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Types PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Id)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Types
VALUES
 ('Type1')
,('Type2')
,('Type3')
,('Type4')
,('Type5')
GO

CREATE TABLE Transactions
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
TypeId INT NULL,
TransactionNumber INT NOT NULL,
Amount MONEY NULL,
DateRecorded DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Transactions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Id),
CONSTRAINT FK_Types FOREIGN KEY(TypeId) REFERENCES Types(Id)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Transactions
VALUES
 (1,55,2555.50,SYSDATETIME())
,(3,55,3555.50,SYSDATETIME())
,(4,55,4555.50,SYSDATETIME())
,(5,55,5555.50,SYSDATETIME())
GO
```

I need a single row returned for each transaction number in the Transactions table.

What I already tried:

```
SELECT TransactionNumber
    ,(CASE WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type1
    ,(CASE WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type2
    ,(CASE WHEN TypeId = 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type3
    ,(CASE WHEN TypeId = 4 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type4
    ,(CASE WHEN TypeId = 5 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type5
FROM Transactions
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT TransactionNumber FROM Transactions` Or do you have other columns as well? if so please try adding an expected output.

Comment: When any answer meet your requirement, you should vote it as an answer. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TransactionNumber
    ,sum(CASE WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type1
    ,sum(CASE WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type2
    ,sum(CASE WHEN TypeId = 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type3
    ,sum(CASE WHEN TypeId = 4 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type4
    ,sum(CASE WHEN TypeId = 5 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type5
FROM Transactions group by TransactionNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do a `PIVOT` to get required output:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ty.NAME, ISNULL(Amount,0)Amount
    FROM TRANSACTIONS t
    INNER JOIN Types ty ON ty.Id = t.TypeId
    WHERE TransactionNumber = 55
    ) sub
PIVOT(
      SUM(Amount) FOR [Name] IN ([Type1], [Type2], [Type3], [Type4], [Type5])
     ) AS pivottable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29af9/7)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) '# Transactions Type 1'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) '# Transactions Type 2'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) '# Transactions Type 3'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) '# Transactions Type 4'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) '# Transactions Type 5'
FROM TRANSACTIONS
Where TransactionNumber = 55
```

You can find a working **[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29af9/5)**.

**EDIT**:

After you comment I think what you are actually looking for is `SUM()`.

```
SELECT TransactionNumber
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type1
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type2
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type3
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 4 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type4
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 5 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type5
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY TransactionNumber
```

SQLFiddle for 2nd query [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29af9/11).

Comment: Pardon me for not including what I've already tried, this is what I've tried thus far

'SELECT 
TransactionNumber
,(CASE WHEN TypeId=1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type1
,(CASE WHEN TypeId=2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type2
,(CASE WHEN TypeId=3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type3
,(CASE WHEN TypeId=4 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type4
,(CASE WHEN TypeId=5 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type5
FROM Transactions'

Comment: You should add this to the Question. Also what changes you expect to this.

Comment: @Rafta Ok, I added your query to the qestion and updated my answer with what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select Id,
       sum(case TypeId when 1 then Amount end) Type1,
       sum(case TypeId when 2 then Amount end) Type2,
       ...
from Transactions
group by Id
```